# how to write a makefile for gitlab -ci for python code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I would like to write a makefile for my python project, and would like to run this project at amazon airflow called (mwaa). Can somebody help me with link or any video where I can learn to write a makefile step by step, and also if it has some packaging steps for deployment to mwaa.
Apologies I am new into gitlab CI-CD and have no clue about the deployment process.